# Wave equation for spatially incoherent light beam

Tags: optics, diffraction

I would like to know what happens to a plane wave from a laser 
$$\Psi(r)=e^{ikr}$$
after it passes a ground glass.

Would I just get a superposition of spherical waves?
$$\Psi(r) = \sum_n\frac{e^{ikr_n}}{ r_n}$$

Comment: Yes. You are right. But initial phase of each wave should be added too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ground glass is a very good diffuser, which means you not only have light being re-emitted in a  [near-Lambertian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert%27s_cosine_law) pattern but with a pretty decent decoherence as well.  So not only do you need an angular dependence (solid angle) for the amplitude, but also a random phase angle.  I don't know how much local phase angle correlation (i.e. the likelihood of the phase being constant over some small solid angle) is found in real-world experiments. Perhaps, if you don't mind a bunch of messy math, you might read about the analogous situation in atmospheric transmission, where there's the [Fried Parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fried_parameter) which describes the local uniformity of atmospheric "patches."